# Fake a bean with SpringBoot test on an Integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test

Same as @MockBean and @SpyBean, is there something similar to @FakeBean / @DummyBean ?

The idea is that the instance is 100% real (with expected production internal state) and it overrides (or adds the bean in case it's not declared on the configuration) the one in the context. Ideally you don't need to create a TestConfiguration class and set it as Primary because that way you control the fake in a per-test basis, only when you need it. Otherwise it uses the main one.

It is very useful when the bean is a context data collector, for instance, so it might be cleant with MockReset.AFTER each test.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this. Is @SpyBean the way to go, even if we don't really spy?

Comment: I think it is not good idea. Creating beans by automatically can have big overhead, because the process in some cases step-by step will be created whole context. Better to create TestContext and control the bean creation, because where need you create real beans and where need you create mock. If you create mock , the beans inside it will not be created and not be required for your test context, in contrast to the automatic process.

Comment: Can you write an answer with this, ill approve as I heard that explanation from other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not good idea. Creating beans by automatically can have big overhead, because the process in some cases step-by step will be created whole context. Better to create TestContext and control the bean creation, because where need you create real beans and where need you create mock. If you create mock , the beans inside it will not be created and not be required for your test context, in contrast to the automatic process.

**PS**.Spring has good error explanation (related to the required bean declaration) and `@MockBean` or `@SpyBean` can be declared on class level with multiple classes for easy and fast declaration.